# Generate Multiple page document from multiple line in excel

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel I have multiple line like this:

```
Name  Age Tel 
John  5    12345677
Peter 10   4547567
Mary  6     46u7687867
```

I am wondering How can I generate multiple document from excel to multiple invoice like this:

page1:

```
Certification of XXXXX

John      Age 5
```

page2:

```
Certification of XXXXX

Peter     Age 10
```

page3:

```
Certification of XXXXX

Mary      Age 6
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need resulting doc being Excel or... which format?

Comment: @fkingan `1.`what do you mean by multiple `documents`? `2.`Do you have an `Excel template` that act as an invoice for you? `3.`Do you have large number of records in Excel? `4.`How many documents are you planning to create? `5.`Could this be sort of a printing job?

Comment: I use the resulted doc for printing only, so all format are good.
@bonCodigo there are around 40 records in Excel, I need to generate a document for each line in Excel. I have already a Excel template and I have to copy and parse around 40 times every month in order to print the certification. I was finding the way to automatize the process.

Comment: @fkingan So it's not a document (like word) but an Excel template? Meaning you want to print the Excel template for each name and age? Just to confirm one more time.

Comment: @bonCodigo it would be great if an Excel template can do the job for me. I just want to print the generated page :)

Comment: Can you show us your proper document template that you have? And what is `Certification of XXXXX` xxxxx?

Comment: Here is a sample Excel https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1409368/sample.xlsx Now I have to copy the information on the list page to the invoice page and print, I am looking for a faster way to automatize it :)

Comment: @fkingan sample is fine, but could you please specify exactly destination cells on the invoice page where list data should be pasted to?

Comment: @PeterL. sure,   for example, I will copy the Name to F40, Price to I38 and Date to I9

Comment: @fkingan It's better to prepare the invoices first and then do the print job - else you end up with quite some traffic here: Going back and forth to sheets/code/sheets/code/printer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the above input & comments, the following code will do the job:

```
Sub ListPrinting()

Dim i As Long

i = 1

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Range("F40").Formula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Formula
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Range("I38").Formula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Formula
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Range("I9").Formula = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Formula
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:="pdfFactory Pro on FPP4:" 'Specify your printer

Next i

MsgBox i - 2 & " invoice(s) printed."

End Sub
```

Please note:

1. You should specify the name of desired printer - use macro-recorder and just select it in the list of available printers on Print dialog.
2. The amount of records in list is practically unlimited... well, paper and ink / toner are not))) All of them will be printed starting row 2 and up to the last non-empty string found on the `list` sheet.
3. Test the code on 1-2 items to avoid paper loss)

Sample file is shared (code tested as well): https://www.dropbox.com/s/296e200496gd7gb/ListPrinting.xlsm

P.S. Perhaps you should reformat the Date field as you desire - it uses regional settings and therefore will be displayed for you differently.

Comment: @fkingan happy to help, enjoy quick printing!)

Answer (score -1):

For generating multiple page document lines from multiple line in excel you should flow 
some steps and for knowing that you can visit http://fetchflow.com/support/question/How-do-I-create-a-new-purchase-order.html

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.